# How can I dynamically get the system architecture?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, architecture, x86, 64-bit

Well as the title says

is there any way to get the system architecture within c++?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to detect if your application is being *compiled* for x86 or x86_64 or if your x86 application is running on a x86_64 machine? Is the distinction you need just x86/x86_64 or you need to distinguish other architectures? Do you need such detection at precompilation-time (to use in #if statements), compile-time (e.g. for templates specialization, array sizes, ...) or runtime?

Comment: Additionally, are you asking about the CPU architecture, the OS architecture (you can run 32-bit Windows on a 64-bit CPU), or a specific process architecture (a 32-bit process can run on 64-bit Windows)?

Comment: Why? Stating your requirement for this info might help you get a more useful answer for your scenario.

Comment: I have a use case: I'm installing a 32-bit C++ app talking to a 32/64-bit C# DLL. My installer needs to know which flavour to install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on "dynamically" and "Visual C++", I'm going to guess you want to do this at run-time under Windows.

In that case, you can use [`GetSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724381%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [`GetNativeSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724340%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to retrieve some basic information about the system and processor. If you need more information about the processor and specific features it supports, you can use [`IsProcessorFeaturePresent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724482%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to find them (though it can be a little awkward for this purpose -- you have to ask about each feature individually, and gives a Boolean answer for each).

Answer (score 3):

```
#if defined(_M_X64)
...
#endif
```

Comment: Platform specific, but indeed I don't think there are better precompilation-time ways to detect this.

Comment: You can compile an executable for 32-bit mode but run it on an x64 machine.

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice big list [here](http://predef.sourceforge.net/prearch.html). The macros are different for Visual Studio and GCC, but just check if they're defined with `#ifdef`.

Something like:

```
#if defined(_M_IX86) || defined(__i386__)
```

Should give you GCC, Visual Studio, and several others.

Answer (score 1):

You can always mix in a few lines of inline assembly and call CPUID to identify the CPU your code is executing on. See this paper as for how to do it:

http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/appnote/241618.pdf

Answer (score 1):

On x64 platforms `sizeof(void*)` returns 8. On x32 platforms `sizeof(void*)` returns 4. This should also be cross platform.