# How do I detect the architecture of a process on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know a process is 32-bit or 64-bit programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953377/how-to-know-a-process-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-programmatically)

I'm writing an app that injects a dll into other applications.  In order for this to work properly, I need to know if the other application is running in 32 or 64 bit mode.  Is there any way to detect this, without attempting to parse the PE header of the application?

Please do *not* suggest [IsWow64Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139%28VS.85%29.aspx).  This does not do what I want, specifically this bit makes it useless:

```
If the process is a 64-bit application running under 64-bit Windows, the value is also set to FALSE.
```

Comment: What language? I assume C or C++

Comment: May not be the best way. But can we try looking at size of int ptr and based on its size, determine if 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: That's won't help.  It would let me detect the architecture of my process, but it would not help in detecting the architecture of the other process (which is not controlled by me)

Comment: Wouldn't it work to obtain the information you need anyway? First check the environment your application is running on; if it's 32-bit, then all processes will be 32-bit. If you're on 64-bit AND IsWow64Process() returns True, then the process is running in 32-bit mode, otherwise 64.

Comment: Just out curiosity,are you writing some "crack" program?

Comment: Just info see http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.in/2009/06/how-to-create-global-system-windows.html and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: It's a compatibility shim, not a crack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code from this page, it takes the size of an int to check, if you want this in C#.

[How to determine programmatically whether a particular process is 32-bit or 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953377/how-to-know-a-process-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-programmatically)

Or perhaps this in C++.

[How can I dynamically get the system architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073815/how-can-i-dynamically-get-the-system-architecture)

Comment: The C# code is pretty much what I want to do.  I just realized that IsWow64Process is indeed what I want, I just need to make sure I'm running on a 64bit machine before using it.

Comment: @devicenull Nice :) But seriously good luck.

Comment: I don't think posting links to other question/answer are worthy answers. There are always comments for that.