# c++17 how can i get the CPU architecture cross platform

Tags: c++, cpu-architecture

basically, I like to get the type of the  CPU architecture the app is running on
similar to node.js [os.arch()](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_arch) or [process.arch](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_arch)
it can be any C++/C library that i can link to my app
but not Qt as i can't use it

**update**

this is what in node.js

```
 function arch(): string;
    /**
     * Returns a string identifying the kernel version.
     * On POSIX systems, the operating system release is determined by calling
     * [uname(3)][]. On Windows, `pRtlGetVersion` is used, and if it is not available,
     * `GetVersionExW()` will be used. See
     * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname#Examples for more information.
     */
```

Comment: The only thing I've seen that's somewhat related is [getting number of threads supported](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency). I would imagine that everything beyond that is dependant on the OS and would need to be dealt with for each case.

Comment: [`std::hardware_destructive_interference_size` & `std::hardware_constructive_interference_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size) are also somewhat hardware related but I think gcc has refused to implement those.

Comment: @user63898 I didn't downvote - but it can't be done using only standard C++. You'll have to use OS specific functions.

Comment: what platform is this for?

Comment: Doesn't make much sense, unlike Javascript C++ is a compiled language.  With cpu-specific machine code as the compile result.  So you have to pick the architecture *before* you compile.  At runtime you would just get back what you already knew before.

Comment: Remember, there are desktops, laptops and *embedded systems*.  I know a lot of embedded systems that run C++, but don't disclose any information about their processors or system on a chip.

Comment: how the node.js do it ? it can be also C/C++ library that do it ( no Qt )

Comment: @user63898  they probably use OS Apis like Window's `GetSystemInfo`, or Linux's `/proc/cpuinfo`. So it depends on what platform you're compiling for

Comment: update the question on how nodejs do it

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with standard C++. If you use Qt, [`QSysInfo::currentCpuArchitecture()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsysinfo.html#currentCpuArchitecture) does exactly what you want.

Comment: How does this work?  There are embedded systems that run C++ and don't broadcast anything about their processors or how the addressing is mapped.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it obviously only works on systems Qt supports.

Comment: how does Qt do it ? is there some c/c++ library that extract the code from them ?
i can't use Qt

Comment: @user63898 Qt probably wraps around the OS-specific code. Qt is opensource, so you can check out their source coded to see how it's exactly done.

Comment: @user63898: For just the arch, probably it's a big `#ifdef __x86_64__` / `#ifdef __arm__` / etc.  chain for all the architectures Qt supports so hopefully that function can inline as a compile-time-constant string. (Maybe some per-compiler variation to which macros to check for.)  OTOH the linked docs say " due to the nature of the operating system functions being used", which may mean at runtime (like `uname`), but might just mean at Qt config time to hard-code a value.

Comment: @user63898 Alternatively, they can use OS Apis like Window's [`GetSystemInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsysteminfo), or Linux's `/proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, this has been asked for Windows previously [How can I dynamically get the system architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4073815/10147399). Qt probably does something like that on each system.

Comment: i updated ths question with the solution on how node.js do it

Comment: @user63898 [Here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/global/qglobal.cpp?h=5.9#n2447) is how Qt does it. It's a messy bit of code.

Comment: here is how CommonCpp do it :
https://www.programcreek.com/cpp/?code=chronoxor%2FCppCommon%2FCppCommon-master%2Fsource%2Fsystem%2Fenvironment.cpp